# Move two or more objects randomly around the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to animate UIImageview to move randomly around the screen. For one UIImageView it is working fine. But for two or more objects it is not working. Can anyone help me?

```
-(void)animationLoop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {          
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];          
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];             
    CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);        
    CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);           
    CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);         
    image.center = squarePostion;     
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];       
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show what you've done so far.

Comment: Yeah, please add relevant code snippets

Comment: i have added the code what i have written.

Comment: Now put the code of the 2 images...

Comment: You are setting the center of only one image and that image will be moved to that position. If you set for second, then only that will be moved.

Comment: @AntonioMG i tried to give CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % 4 self.view.bounds.size.width); but it is showing error. I dont know what i atrying to do is right or wrong

Comment: @Aadhira i had set it for second one also but both get colaps and become one image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially when you want to start the animation, start the animation as below.

```
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:number1];          
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];             
CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);        
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);           
CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);         
imgView1.center = squarePostion;     
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];   
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];
[UIView commitAnimations];    


number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:number1];          
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];             
x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);        
y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);           
squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);         
imgView2.center = squarePostion;     
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];       
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And your `animationLoop:finished:context:` method should be as follows.

```
-(void)animationLoop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {          
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];          
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];             
    CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);        
    CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);           
    CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);   

    int i = [(NSNumber*)context intValue];
    if( i == 0 )
    {
        imgView1.center = squarePostion;    
    }
    else
    {
        imgView2.center = squarePostion;    
    }
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];       
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}
```

Make the changes as mentioned above and try it. You would get what you required.

Comment: This is done with 2 imageviews. If you have array of imageviews, then you could do that with a `for` loop.

Comment: How can write this line  CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width); in swift.

Comment: @Ilanchezhian According to your answer do we need to declare the objects as class variables to do that? Assuming the objects are added dynamically, Do we need to declare them as class variables? Here in the example, imgView1 and imgView2 are declared as class variables. How about having more than 10 objects in the screen?